# Securing an IMAP service

Tags: email, port-knocking

I need to secure an IMAP service running on `dovecot`.

Which wrapping layers of security can I enhance security with?

I am using most of the built-in `dovecot`-specific security features, like encryption and secure authentication/databases, so I am interested in OS-level tweaks that play well with offering IMAPS.

- e.g. for such a system, would port-knocking add or subtract hardness?

Environment: `debian`.

Answer (score 1):

this depends if it is public or not.

if private:

- use vpn-access, so you imap-server will be invisible to the outside, or
- listen on another port than standard
- use a tcpwrapper/iptables to restrict access onyl for certain ips

if private or public:

- enable TLS
- log failed attempts
- monitor your server (Nagios, Splunk, OSSEC)
- use iptables anyway

sceuring debian:

- please [Read This Fine Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/index.en.html#contents)

Comment: The link is broken.